# Simplify $2 \sin(x) \cos(7x) + \sin(6x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing a problem and in my chain of computations I arrived at a seemingly complicated function 
$$2 \sin(x) \cos(7x) + \sin(6x)$$

However, I typed it into Wolfram and was surprised to find
$$2 \sin(x) \cos(7x) + \sin(6x) = \sin(8x)$$

Is there a way I could have seen this beforehand? Even now I'm unsure how I would prove this identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to remember or look up any trig identities at all, you can turn everything into exponentials:

\begin{eqnarray}
2 \sin x \cos (7x) + \sin (6x) &=& 2\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)\left(\frac{e^{7ix}+e^{-7ix}}{2}\right) + \frac{e^{6ix}-e^{-6ix}}{2i}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{8ix}-e^{6ix}+e^{-6ix}-e^{-8ix} + e^{6ix}-e^{-6ix}\right)\\
&=&\frac{e^{8ix}-e^{-8ix}}{2i}\\
&=&\sin(8x)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This one is good because it doesnt involve playing with identities. No intuition required.

Comment: This is my favorite one yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

$$2\sin(x)\cos(7x)+\sin(6x)=2\sin(x)\cos(7x)+\sin(7x-x)$$

$$=2\sin(x)\cos(7x)+\sin(7x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(7x)$$

$$=\sin(x)\cos(7x)+\sin(7x)\cos(x)=\sin(8x)$$

Comment: Ah yes, I think if I was more experienced I could have seen that $6x = 7x - x$

Comment: I found that tricky as well.

Comment: I believe things can be largely simplified: see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

There is a group of identities called the *product-to-sum* identities (Wikipedia has a [very useful list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) of such things); the one that's relevant here is as follows:
$$\sin\alpha\cos\beta = \frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta) + \sin(\alpha-\beta)}{2}$$

Applying the above, we have:

$$\begin{align}
2\sin x \cos 7x + \sin 6x &= 2\big( \frac{\sin 8x + \sin (-6x)}{2}\big) + \sin 6x\\
&=\sin 8x -\sin6x + \sin 6x\\
&=\sin 8x 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh cool. I like this because it's more of a forward direction than the other answer which is like working backwards.

Comment: @Mark, $\$3$rd of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

Another method. Take the derivative, which ends up being $8\cos(8x)$, and then integrate to get $\sin(8x)$

Comment: But is it easier to show the derivative is $8 \cos(8x)$?

Comment: Easier? Maybe, maybe not. I never liked using identities, so I usually do a calculus approach. This is just my way of doing it.

Comment: The other answer is a bit more elegant, and is easier for those who dont know any calculus.

Comment: If you do this, you also have to check that the original function matches $\sin(8x)$ at some point. Otherwise you could be off by a constant.

Comment: @Micah Good point, forgot to mention that. The $+c$ can be the hardest part to remember sometimes